# Factory methods in Ninject C#

Tags: c#, ninject

I have an interface called IBreakfastProvider, which has several implementations.  Currently my code decides which one to use based off an id. It uses a factory method, like this:

```
public IBreakfastProvider GetBreakfastProvider(int id)
{
    switch (id)
    {
        case 1:
            return new CornFlakeProvider(new SomeDependency());
        case 2:
            return new MuesliProvider(new SomeOtherDependency());
        case 3:
            return new ToastProvider();
        default:
            throw new ApplicationException("Unknown provider id."); 
    }
}
```

Each implementation of IBreakfast provider can have its own dependencies.  How could this method be replaced to use Ninject to work out which implementation to use based of this integer id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register each type with a name. Then, when you need to resolve, simply pass the `id` to Ninject:

```
// Use better naming though :)
kernel.Bind<IBreakfastProvider>().To<CornFlakeProvider>().Named("1");
```

And then when you resolve:

```
var breakfastProvider = resolutionRoot.Get<IFoo>(id);
```

Comment: and instead of doing `resolution.Get<IFoo>(id);` you can also use [this Ninject.Extensions.Factory feature](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki/Factory-interface%3A-Referencing-Named-Bindings)

Answer (score 1):

Use constructor injection:

```
public class BreakfastProviderFactory
{
    private readonly CornFlakeProvider provider1;
    private readonly MuesliProvider provider2;
    private readonly ToastProvider provider3;

    public BreakfastProviderFactory(CornFlakeProvider provider1,
        MuesliProvider provider2, ToastProvider provider3) {
    {
        this.provider1 = provider1;
        this.provider2 = provider2;
        this.provider3 = provider3;
    }

    public IBreakfastProvider GetBreakfastProvider(int id)
    {
        switch (id)
        {
            case 1: return this.provider1;
            case 2: return this.provider2;
            case 3: return this.provider3;
            default: throw new ApplicationException("Unknown provider id."); 
        }
    }
}
```